# How to combine two same blocks into a single one?

Tags: ruby

How can I use a single block in this:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
  u.permit(:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
  u.permit(:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the definition of [`for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/a29fee164449561f177b2f3f404c41d03741095d/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L12), you can see that the `kind` argument is being used as the key to the `@blocks` hash. Maybe that is a sign that you shouldn't try to "combine" those two statements.

If you purely want to re-use the codes in the block, just use [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html). So something like:

```
block = Proc.new do |u| 
  u.permit(:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) 
end

devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up, block)
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update, block)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Proc`  helps you, Try following,

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up, &your_method)
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update, &your_method)

def your_method
  Proc.new { |u| u.permit(:full_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```